# IIS Express showing Forbidden when accessed from VM

Tags: iis, iis-express

I've got various websites on my local machine, and I'm trying to test a client within a VM that needs to access one of the sites. I've added a line to the VM's hosts file that makes `localhost` point to the Host IP Address.

All of the sites are on https with a certificate assigned to `localhost` and signed by a CA that's trusted by the VM.

The VM can access all of the sites, apart from one that's running on IIS Express. For the one that's running on IIS Express, I can access it fine with the IP Address or another hostname, but with `localhost` it comes back as forbidden.

I also put another line in the hosts file that points another domain at the same ip address as localhost, and that worked as well.

So on the VM:

- https://localhost/Site1 **works**, points to another site running on regular IIS
- https://localhost:44134 **doesn't work, 403 Forbidden**, points to IIS Express
- https://10.0.11.10:44134 **works**, points to IIS Express
- https://machinename:44134 **works**, points to IIS Express
- https://different.domain.com:44134 **works**, points to IIS Express

I've checked the binding in IIS Express and it's like this, which I believe is correct:

```
<binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:44314:" />
```

And the urlacl is this, which I think is correct also:

```
Reserved URL            : https://*:44314/
    User: \Everyone
        Listen: Yes
        Delegate: No
        SDDL: D:(A;;GX;;;WD)
```

Is there something special with localhost? The VM is running Windows 7.

---

Edit:

I've created a new Asp.net MVC app that runs on **http** (so not using https this time) and port 57811.

- http://localhost:57811 **doesn't work, 403 Forbidden**, points to IIS Express
- http://10.0.11.10:57811 **works**, points to IIS Express
- http://machinename:57811 **works**, points to IIS Express
- http://different.domain.com:57811 **works**, points to IIS Express

So the issue is nothing to do with https, or the specific site.